# Flutter - Customizing Default Splash Screen Image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, splash-screen

I've been trying to customize my splash screen, but the image that I'm setting its having a white background instead of blending with the background

**NOTE: i already tried to use only the logo without the shape but it disappeared because its white**
**NOTE: i tried to use flutter_native_splash pkg but i didn't get the result that i want**

[here is the image that im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5Mu.png)

[and this is the result that i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qVcf.png)

here is my launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_color" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image"
            android:drawable="@color/background_color"  />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and here is the style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

here i made a file to set the background color color.xml

````
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="background_color">#409CFF</color>
</resources>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own SplashScreen like this way

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'splash_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main_screen.dart'; // Import your main screen widget

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigateToHome();
  }

  _navigateToHome() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {});
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Your Logo Here',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i override the default splash screen ?